# Passing primitive array to function with std::initializer_list argument

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

With the a function taking std::initializer_list as argument like shown below

```
int sumOf(std::initializer_list<int> numbers) {
    int sum = 0;  
    for (auto x : numbers) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This code works

`auto sum = sumOf({ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });`

but not this

```
 int i[]  = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
 auto x = sumOf(i);
```

Why does the second form not work? Or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**
From the gcc 4.7.2 implementation of std::intializer_list, the constructor of intializer_list is private and compiler needs to pass the size of the array.

```
  // The compiler can call a private constructor.
  constexpr initializer_list(const_iterator __a, size_type __l)
  : _M_array(__a), _M_len(__l) { }
```

I guess the compiler cannot judge the size of the array from the variable "i" in certain cases. If so, passing static array to intializer_list cannot be supported by the compiler (?).

Comment: But `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }` really created a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: Well, one passes an initializer list, as excepted by the function, and the other passes and array, what else should happen. An initializer list is not just an array. What about changing it to `auto i = { ... };`, not sure if this works, though.

Comment: @ChristianRau - it works with `auto i = { ... };` but "i" seems to be no more behaving as an int array.

Comment: @KiranMohan No, because now it is a `std::initializer_list`, which is the type expected by the function, and which is totally different from an array.

Answer (score 3):

`i` is not an `initializer_list`. `initializer_list` is not some shorthand for "static array". It's a special object that can only be created (outside of copy-construction) by using a braced-init-list (ie: `{...}` syntax).

When you do `int i[] = {...};` you are performing aggregate initialization on an *array*. `i` is an array of `int`s, not an `initializer_list`.

What you want is a template function, which can take anything you can use range-based-for over:

```
template<typename Rng>
int sumOf(const Rng &numberRange) {
    int sum = 0;  
    for (auto x : numberRange) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: the template version does not work when directly passing values with the `{...}` syntax unless you have specialized version of sumOf() which takes std::initializer_list

Comment: @KiranMohan: Currently, that's correct and the only discrepancy between `auto` and normal template argument deduction. There's a proposal to have that fixed in C++Next, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the index tuple trick, as used by many people before

```
template<int N, int ...X>
struct I : struct I<N-1, N, X...> {};

template<int X...>
struct I<0, X...> {
  typedef I type;
};

template<typename F, typename T, int N, int ...X>
decltype(f(std::declval<std::initializer_list<T>>()))
make_list(T const (&a)[N], F f, I<X...>) 
{
   return f(std::initializer_list<T>{a[X]...});
}

template<typename F, typename T, int N>
decltype(f(std::declval<std::initializer_list<T>>()))
make_list(T const(&a)[N], F f) {
   return make_list(a, f, typename I<N-1>::type());
}
```

Usage is easy

```
make_list(i, &sumOf);
```

Or using a lambda

```
make_list(i, [](std::initializer_list<int> x) {
  return sumOf(x);
});
```